# How can I turn off all commenting across WordpressMU

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpressMu as a tool for creating feed content. Ideally I don't want users to see the actual website and especially not comment.

Is there an easy way to disable commenting by default.

Obviously I could hack or comment out some code, but it would be nice if there was a plugin or option I could use to do it in a best practice way.

Note: this is wordpress mu

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

That's a farily serious retasking of MU; probably better off asking in [Wordpress MU forums](http://mu.wordpress.org/forums/) and among the MU hackers.